# Dynamic binding to any tab control - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to set the max width of the grid of a view, however I want to be able to put this view anywhere within any tab control, as the width of the grid is determined by the tab control it's within. I don't want to have to specify the specific tab control by name because I want it to work with any tab control.

Does anyone know how I can change the below XAML code? This is in the `WeUserControl` view

```
    <Grid.MaxWidth>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WeMaxWidthConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="mainWindowTabControl" Path="ActualWidth"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Grid.MaxWidth>
```

In the view that it is being used in, it is literally just:

```
<views:WeUserControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
```

and that is encapsulated in a tab control, in this case, called `mainWindowTabControl`

Comment: If it's always a tabcontrol you can just use relativesource binding with an elementype of tabcontrol https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/relativesource-markupextension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the tabcontrol you're looking for and the grid will be within the visual tree of this.

The relativesource binding would be:

```
<Binding Path="ActualWidth" 
         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a *public property* called "TabControl" to the parent window that returns a reference to the `TabControl`, you should be able to bind to it like this from any child element of the window:

```
<Binding Path="TabControl.ActualWidth" 
         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" />
```